# :nth-of-type(3n) Stops Working After 21st Item

Tags: wordpress, css-selectors

I am utilizing a WordPress archive template (archive.php) to echo the featured thumbnails of 50 posts, which then link to the corresponding posts. Following is the code that does that:

```
<div class="content">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post (); ?>

   <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <div class="item">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'featuredImageCropped' ); ?>
                    <div class="archive-title">
                        <h4>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div> <!--end #post -->

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <p>Sorry, we've got nothing for you!</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div> <!-- end .content -->
```

And here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="content">

        <div id="post-189" class="post-189 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-michigan">

            <a href="https://benstewartdesign.com/julianbunker/2019/08/22/birch-sunrise/" title="Birch Sunrise" rel="bookmark">
                <div class="item">
                    <img width="600" height="400" src="https://benstewartdesign.com/julianbunker/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Michigan-Birch-Sunrise.jpg" class="attachment-featuredImageCropped size-featuredImageCropped wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://benstewartdesign.com/julianbunker/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Michigan-Birch-Sunrise.jpg 1620w, https://benstewartdesign.com/julianbunker/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Michigan-Birch-Sunrise-300x200.jpg 300w, https://benstewartdesign.com/julianbunker/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Michigan-Birch-Sunrise-768x512.jpg 768w, https://benstewartdesign.com/julianbunker/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Michigan-Birch-Sunrise-1024x683.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px">                      <div class="archive-title">
                        <h4>
                            Birch Sunrise                           </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

</div> <!-- end .content -->
```

And it loops the `<div id="post-..."></div>` 50 times and it breaks on the 22nd item.

Following is the CSS that styles this page for desktop size screens:

```
.content { 
    width:942px;
}
.item {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    width: 32%;
    margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
    float: left;
}
.item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.archive .post:nth-of-type(3n) .item {
    margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
.item .archive-title {
    width: 100%;
    top: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
}
.item .archive-title h4 {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 300;
    display: none;
}
.item:hover .archive-title h4 {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This works perfectly to create a three-column grid for MOST of the page, but after the 7th instance of the `nth-of-type(3n)` rule the grid breaks and this rule is NOT applied.

This is a bit hard to explain and an anomaly amongst any CSS issue I've experienced. Here is a screenshot of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEHzf.jpg

I've tried nth-child vs. nth-of-type to no avail.

This issue is present in Chrome as well as Safari, but in Safari the grid break doesn't happen until the last row, so 16th instance of (3n), which is even more confusing.

Thanks for everyone help.

Comment: This doesn't happen on my device. The bottom border seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately I wasn't referring to a bottom border, I was referring the 7th instance of nth-child(3n) breaking. Following is a screenshot of the issue: https://benstewartdesign.com/julianbunker/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Screen-Shot-2019-08-22-at-11.55.23-AM.png

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I've now elaborated on the problem in the initial post, thanks

Comment: Please do not use your own site to host images about your question. This raised some SPAM flags. See this post about sharing images: [Why StackExchange use imgur to host images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350433/why-does-stack-exchange-use-imgur-to-host-images)

Comment: Sorry Steve, i have uploaded the screenshot Imgur and updated the link above. Noted for the future as well.

Comment: We also need the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Where's the rest of the CSS for `.post`? Are you using floats? Is it a flex item?

Comment: The only CSS rule that applies to `.post` in the entire sheet is `.archive .post:nth-of-type(3n) .item { margin: 0 0 2% 0; }`. The class `.item` is floated left, which you can see in the CSS I pasted here. There are no flex items in the document.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I was facing wasn't an error with the code, but it was two of the 50 post didn't have an assigned featured image, which caused the grid alignment to break.

Thank you for bearing with a Stack Overflow newbie here and I will keep your community guidelines in mind for future posts.